# What is the difference between 'is' and '==' in Dart?

Tags: dart

Let's say I have:

```
class Test<T> {
  void method() {
    if (T is int) {
      // T is int
    } 

    if (T == int) {
      // T is int
    }
  }
}
```

I know I can override `==` operator but what's the main difference between `==` and `is` in Dart if I don't override any operator.

---

**Edit:**

Say I have

```
extension MyIterable<T extends num> on Iterable<T> {
  T sum() {
    T total = T is int ? 0 : 0.0; // setting `T == int` works
    for (T item in this) {
      total += item;
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

And when I use my extension method with something like:

```
var addition = MyIterable([1, 2, 3]).sum();
```

I get this error:

> type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [`identical(x, y)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/identical.html) checks if `x` is the same object as `y`.
- `x == y` checks whether `x` should be considered equal to `y`.  The [*default* implementation for `operator ==`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) is the same as `identical()`,  but `operator ==` can be overridden to do deep equality checks (or in theory could be pathological and be implemented to do anything).
- `x is T` checks whether `x` has type `T`. `x` is an *object instance*.

```dart
class MyClass {
  MyClass(this.x);

  int x;

  @override
  bool operator==(dynamic other) {
    return runtimeType == other.runtimeType && x == other.x;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => x.hashCode;
}

void main() {
  var c1 = MyClass(42);
  var c2 = MyClass(42);
  var sameC = c1;

  print(identical(c1, c2));    // Prints: false
  print(identical(c1, sameC)); // Prints: true

  print(c1 == c2);    // Prints: true
  print(c1 == sameC); // Prints: true

  print(c1 is MyClass);      // Prints: true
  print(c1 is c1);           // Illegal.  The right-hand-side must be a type.
  print(MyClass is MyClass); // Prints: false
}
```

Note the last case: `MyClass is MyClass` is `false` because the left-hand-side is a *type*, not an *instance* of `MyClass`. (`MyClass is Type` would be `true`, however.)

In your code, `T is int` is incorrect because both sides are types.  You *do* want `T == int` in that case.  Note that `T == int` would check for an *exact* type and would not be true if one is a derived type of the other (e.g. `int == num` would be false).

Comment: This is probably the best answer, thank you so much sir, I wish I could upvote it more.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, **== is equality operator** and **"is" is the instanceof operator** of Dart (If you come from Java background, if not, it basically tells you if something is of type something).

Use == for equality, when you want to check if two objects are equal. You can implement the == operator (method) in your class to define on what basis do you want to judge if two objects are equal.

Take this example:

```
class Car {
    String model;
    String brand;
    Car(this.model, this.brand);

    bool operator == (otherObj) {
        return (otherObj is Car && other.brand == brand); //or however you want to check
        //On the above line, we use "is" to check if otherObj is of type Car
    }
}
```

Now you can check if two cars are "equal" based on the condition that you have defined.

```
void main() {
  final Car micra = Car("Micra", "Nissan");
  print(micra == Car("Micra", "Nissan")); // true
  print(micra is Car("Micra", "Nissan")); // true
}
```

Hence, == is something you use to decide if two objects are equal, you can override and set it as per your expectations on how two objects should be considered equal.

On the other hand, "is" basically tells you if an instance is of type object (micra is of type Car here).

Comment: The Dart Language Tour has sections on [equality operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#equality-and-relational-operators) and [type](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators) operators.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you, does it mean that if two objects are equal they will always be identical?

Comment: @iKeepChangingName No. `identical` means the exact same object instance.  Two separate objects can be `==` (have the same internal values) but will not be `identical`.

Comment: @ Yudhishthir Singh Thanks for your answer, I already knew identical and equality stuff, I have edited my code, you can see if I use `==` the code works but on using `is` it fails, I was expecting the opposite of it. Could you please explain why the error is there?

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you so much sir, you have been very helpful, I have updated my code, could you please tell me what's wrong with it, I'll be glad if you can post an answer. Thanks again :)