# The name 'string' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is' expression

Tags: flutter, dart

During unit testing of a function returning different types of objects, I need to check if the type of returned object is the same as expected. Therefore, I need to pass multiple classes inside a variable. Then I need to use this variable with the `is` operator to check types.

```
final string = String;
assert('foo' is string);
```

But I am getting

```
error: The name 'string' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is' expression.
```

I read somewhere that a library called `Dart:mirrors` can solve this problem but I haven't seen an actual example.

Comment: Did you mean final String string = "String";?

Comment: Also, it should be assert('foo' is String), with a capital S

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553561/what-is-the-difference-between-is-and-in-dart/61584189#61584189

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer. The trick to create an instance of the type that I want to assert, then use `runtimeType` property.

If a class is called `User` from a.dart and another one is also called `User` from b.dart,  runtimeType won't be the same

```
final string = 'anything'.runtimeType;
assert('foo'.runtimeType is string);
```

Comment: But this is not possible for custom classes. How do you proceed there?

Answer (score -1):

In unit testing, you know the expected answer. There shouldn't be a need to make your types variables.
Instead, just assert with the strong typed

```
assert('foo' is String);
```

Comment: > In unit testing, you know the expected answer.
What if i want to create reusable method to check types? That's pretty rash to say that I shouldn't make my type a variable.