# Dart null vs Null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

As far as a know, checking if a object is `null` or `Null` should be the same thing on Dart.

Something like:

```
print(bar == null);
print(bar is Null);
```

should print the same value. But, in a flutter app using firebase I got the following behaviour:

```
  print(snapshot.data['appearance']['details'].runtimeType); // Null
  print(snapshot.data['appearance']['details'].runtimeType == null); // false
  print(snapshot.data['appearance']['details'].runtimeType == Null); // true
  print(snapshot.data['appearance']['details'].runtimeType is Null); // false
```

the field value is `null` on firebase. Why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`null` is a *value*. `Null` is a *type*.

`.runtimeType` returns a `Type`.  It cannot return a `null` value (that would mean the object has no type).  `null.runtimeType` returns `Null`; that is, the `null` object has a type named `Null`.

As for why `.runtimeType is Null` is `false`, see: [What is the difference between 'is' and '==' in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61553561/)