# How to implement `assert()` for Type / T

Tags: dart, types, assert

to reproduce:

- create an empty project
- paste the code below in `main.dart`
- press f5 (in vs code, else just run the app)

note that [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) [ignores assert](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/310)

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  Foo(this.data) : assert(T is int || T is String);
  final T data;
}

void main() {
  print('hello');
  final _fooInt = Foo<int>(1);
}
```

logs:

```sh
flutter: hello
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:type_test/main.dart': Failed assertion: line 2 pos 27: 'T is int || T is String': is not true.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      new Foo
package:type_test/main.dart:2
#3      main
package:type_test/main.dart:8
#4      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:136:25)
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1186:13)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1090:19)
```

How can I implement correctly the assertion on line 2?
Thank you

Comment: `T is int` and `T is String` don't do what you want.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61553561/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

credit to `Stampi` from the [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5cVi.png) on [r/flutterDev discord](https://discord.com/invite/uMya6wQ)

the change below fixes the issue

```
class Foo<T extends int> {
- Foo(this.data) : assert(T is int || T is String);
+ Foo(this.data) : assert(T == int || T == String);
  final T data;
}

void main() {
  print('hello');
  final _fooInt = Foo<int>(1);
  print(_fooInt.data.runtimeType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart JS backend treats `int`s as `double`. That's why your code doesn't throw an exception. You can read about it [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/int-class.html).

Added. You can try something like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
  Foo(this.data) : assert(T == int || T == String);
  final T data;
}

void main() async {
  print('hello');
  // ok
  final _fooInt = Foo<int>(1);
  // ok
  final _fooStr = Foo<String>("Str");
  // fails
  final _fooDouble = Foo<double>(5.5);
}
```

Comment: thanks I'm ediing the code and the steps to reproduce, I'm not 100% sure that the reason is the one you are describing, anyhow darpad ignore assertions ( I didn't know that!)

Comment: thanks I already posted it following Stampi answer on discors