# Dart Test using type check on Exception is returning wrong result

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, dart-test

I have this test that does fail when run. I am not sure why though since the `a` should be true. Can somebody explain me why?

```dart
  test('test error', () async {
    const error = Exception;
    const a = error is Exception;
    expect(a, true);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`error` is *not* an instance of an `Exception`. `error` is the `Exception` *type*, and [`x is T` checks if `x` is an instance of `T`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584189/).  Therefore:

- `Exception() is Exception` would be true.
- `error is Exception` (equivalent to `Exception is Exception`) would be false.
- `error is Type` (equivalent to `Exception is Exception`) would be true.
- `error == Exception` (equivalent to `Exception == Exception`) would be true.