# Dart: How to check the type of a sometimes nullable generic type?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, nullable, typechecking

Given the following dart 3 snippet, is it possible to match against `A` being nullable in the switch clause, and to find out which kind of nullable `A` is? (`String?`, `int?` etc)
The type checker incorrectly assumes that `A` can never be nullable, and I end up with a case that I can't seem to match against.

```
void main() {
  String? x = test(null);
  String y = test("hi");
}

A test<A extends Object?>(A a) {
  switch((A,a.runtimeType)){
    case (String,Null) :
      print("found miscasted nullable string");
    case (String,_) : 
      print("found non-null string: $a");
    // This case should match, but something is weird.
    case (String?,_) :
      print("found nullable string");
    case (var x,Null):
      print("found something null: $x $a");
      if(x is String?)
        print("$x is String?");
      else
        print("$x is not String?");
    case (_,_):
      print("failed matching completely" ); 
  };
  return a;
}
```

The output becomes

```
found something null: String? null
    String? is not String?
found non-null string: hi
```

and I can't seem to find a way to match the input type against `String?`.

I need this to work in Flutter, so dart:mirror can't be a solution.

**Edit**: Thanks to the answer from @jamesdlin, I now have the following functions in my code:

```
Type typeOf<A>() => A;
bool isSomeKindOf<T,S>() => S == typeOf<T>() || S ==  typeOf<T?>();
```

. This means that now I can do things like

```
bool isIntOrNullableInt<A>(A a) => isSomeKindOf<int,A>();
print(isIntOrNullableInt(3)); // true
print(isIntOrNullableInt(null as Int?)); // true
print(isIntOrNullableInt("3")); // false
```

which means that I can now do stuff like

```
A getOrDefault<A>(String token, A defaultVal) =>
    (
    isSomeKindOf<int,A>() ? source.getInt(token) ?? defaultVal :
    isSomeKindOf<String,A>() ? source.getString(token) ?? defaultVal :
    defaultVal
    ) as A;
```

which works whether `A` is a `Foo` or a `Foo?`, which was my secret agenda all along.
This lets me finally have the following working:

```
String prop1 = getOrDefault("prop1", "property missing");
int? prop2 = getOrDefault("prop2", null);
```

Comment: If it matches Object, it's not null.  And don't use runtimeType for this!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz That answered no part of my question at all. And why should I not use runtimeType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the message from the analyzer (with emphasis added):

> The **null-check pattern** will have no effect because the matched type isn't nullable.

`String?` in your pattern isn't checking `A == String?`, it's treated as a [null-check pattern](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#null-check) which a separate kind of pattern, and that pattern is applied to `String`.

That's also why the analyzer complains about `case (String?, _)` being redundant with `case (String, _)`:

> This case is covered by the previous cases.

Also note that your check `if (x is String?)` won't work either because `x` was matched to `A`, and [`A is B` checks if `A` is an *instance* of `B`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584189/). `String` is *not* an instance of a `String?`; `String` (and `String?`) are instances of the `Type` class.

I'm not sure if you can do what you want with patterns, but you instead could do:

```dart
void main() {
  String? x = test(null);
  String y = test("hi");
}

Type identityType<T>() => T;

A test<A extends Object?>(A a) {
  if (A == String) {
    if (a == null) {
      // Note that this is not possible.
      print("found miscasted nullable string");
    } else {
      print("found non-null string: $a");
    }

    // `A == String?` is not legal syntax.
  } else if (A == identityType<String?>()) {
    print("found nullable string");
  } else if (a == null) {
    print("found something null: $A $a");

    if (A == identityType<String?>()) {
      // This is not possible since it would have been caught earlier.
      print("$A is String?");
    } else {
      print("$A is not String?");
    }
  } else {
    print("failed matching completely");
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Huh, interesting! Yeah, I had no idea about null-check patterns, must have missed that one.

`case (var x, Null):  if(x == identityType<String?>()) // This actually matches! Finally!`

Regarding your comment about `is`, I have an addendum: `x` was mached to `A`, so the `is` check actually fails because `String?` is not an instance of `String?`, just as `String is String` is false, and for the same reason that you said, that `Type` is an instance `String?` or `String`.
Thanks for clearing this gotcha out for me!

Comment: Eh, correction to my own statement: "that `Type` is *not* an instance of `String?` or `String`"